# Sequelize migration doesn't migrate more than one field from model

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to migrate a new table to with Sequelize building a database on PostgreSQL 9.4. After the migration, the table doesn't show more than one field (the first one) and I can't request it neither with my API.

I've tried to write my model using ES5 & ES6, undo all migrations and remigrate, trying to write the model manually using a different table

Here's my index.js for sequelize :

```
[...]
let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database, config.username, config.password, config
  );
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) =>
    (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
    (file !== basename) &&
    (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

and here's model file for my table (named Movies)

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Movies = sequelize.define('Movies', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    year: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    runtime: DataTypes.STRING,
    genre: DataTypes.STRING,
    plot: DataTypes.STRING,
    documentary: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    votes: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  Movies.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return Movies;
};
```

Here's the migration file :

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Movies', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      year: {
        type: Sequelize.NUMBER
      },
      runtime: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      genre: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      plot: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      documentary: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
      },
      votes: {
        type: Sequelize.NUMBER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Movies');
  }
};
```

I expected to have more fields than just the title field, but it always create Movies with only "id, title, createdAt, updateAt" fields.

Comment: can you post Model file for Movies

Comment: that's the second bloc of code @feiiiiii

Comment: that is the migration file . you don't have a model file for Movies ?

Comment: I don't know what they might look like, since I've been "Generating" my models with the command 'sequelize model:create' and it output me that class after some tweaks. Do you have a link to what you're referring ?

Comment: I've edited my comment, the second block of code is the (new) actual model file, and the third one is the migration file. After reverting then migrating, it still shows the title field only.

Comment: this looks like you will create additional table when your code is up and running. the model will look for table name Moviess instead of Movies , can you check ?

Comment: I solved it ! Apparently it was using a previous migration file that did not include the other fields... Still new to this system but you helped me resolve this by looking closer at these files. Thanks a lot !